# fetch api css loader

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, preloader

I'm using fetch API to access a REST API I developed and hosted online. But when retrieving data from the database (>60 rows) to be displayed in a section of the page, it takes about 3-5 seconds to display the data which I styled with HTML and CSS.

My question is how can i implement a css preloader to load before the actual data is displayed. And how do i know that the data has been displayed.

**Below is a part of my code.**

```
// Front end
frontend.html

<table>
<caption>User requests</caption>
<thead class="table-head">
<tr>
    <th scope="col">Request Id</th>
    <th scope="col">User ID</th>
    <th scope="col">Brand</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody id="tablebody">

  <div class="loader" id="loader"></div>

  </tbody>
     </table> 





// file.js
fetch(url, { 
method: 'GET',
headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token}
}).then(response =>{ 
// Redirect the user to the login page
// If the user is not an admin
if(response.status === 401) {
    window.location.replace('./Index.html');
}
return response.json()
})
.then((data) => {  
let completedata = data.allRequests;
if(completedata) {
    completedata.forEach((item) => {
        timeStamp = new Date(item.createdon);
        dateTime = timeStamp.toDateString();
        theOutput +=`<tr id="listofrequests"><a href=""></a><td data- 
label="Request Id">${item.id}</td> </a>
        <td data-label="Brand">${item.userid}</td>
        <td data-label="Brand">${item.brand}</td>
        <td data-label="Type">${item.other}</td>
        <td data-label="Status">${item.name}</td>
        <td data-label="Status"><a href="./Request-status.html" class="btn 
view-detail" id="${item.id}" onClick="adminviewonerequest(this.id)">view</a> 
</td>
<td data-label="Cancel"><button class="danger" id="${item.id}" 
name="${item.name}" onClick="return cancelrequest(this.id, this.name)"><i 
class="fa fa-trash"> Cancel Request</i></button></td>
      </tr>`;
    });
}
else {
    toastr.warning(data.message);
}

document.getElementById('tablebody').innerHTML = theOutput;           
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Is file.js the entry point in a node.js application or an ordinary java script file ?

Comment: It is not the entry point. It's an ordinary javascript file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use on of those already implemented load spinners [How to make a loading spinner in html](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp)

Then , In your html code add `<div id="loading" class="loader"></div>` , Which make the loader displayed by default

and Using fetch :

```
fetch(YouUrl)
.then(res => {
    if(res == 404){
        // To hide the loader when the error is happen , There is no need to use loader 
        // Show some toaster notification for the user or sweet alert 
        document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';   
    }
})
.then(json => {
    // Here is your data so you need to hide the loader 
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = 'none';   
});
```